# Finding a series of numbers that maximise $\ \sum f_i(x_i) $

Tags: algorithms

Let $\ f_1, f_2, ... f_m : \{0, ..., m \} \rightarrow \mathbb Z $

my task is to find an algorithm that find a series of numbers $\ x_1, x_2, ..., x_m \in \{ 0, ..., m \} $ that maximise $\ \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x_i) $ and subjects to $\ \sum_i^m x_i \le m $

To be honest I can't really wrap my head around this problem. Any suggestions on ways to look at this problem differently?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task?  Can you credit the source?

Comment: @D.W. Just home assignment I gotten on data structures and algorithm course I take. Not sure how should I add credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a trivial Dynamic Programming algorithm for your problem:

Let $T$ denote a table of size $(m+1)$ x $(m+1)$.
Here, $T[i][j]$ stores the maximum value of $\sum_{t = 1}^{i}f_{t}(x_{t})$ such that $\sum_{t = 1}^{i}x_{t} \leq j$.

**Induction Case:** Since there are $m+1$ possible choices for $x_{i}$, check each one of them.
$$T[i][j] = \max_{p \in \{0,\dotsc,m\} \textrm{ and } p \leq j} \Big\{T[i-1][j-p] + f_{i}(p)\Big\}$$

**Base Case:** For $i = 0$ means there is no function. Therefore, the value is $0$.
$$T[0][j] = 0 \quad \forall j \in \{0,\dotsc,m\}$$

**Output:** The algorithm will output $T[m][m]$ which is simply the maximum value of $\sum_{t = 1}^{m}f_{t}(x_{t})$ such that $\sum_{t =1}^{m} x_{t} \leq m$

**Running Time Analysis:** Since the size of the table is $O(m^{2})$ and computing each entry takes $O(m)$ time. The overall running time is $O(m^{3})$.

Comment: In the induction case, $p \in \{0, \dots, m\}$ should be $p \in \{0, \dots, j\}$ since otherwise $T[i-1][j-p]$ might not exist.

Comment: I have added an extra condition that $p \leq j$. It should take care of that right?

Comment: Yup! $\phantom{}{}$

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Though I'm not sure I understand why $\ \sum_{t=1}^I x_t \le j $ ?

Comment: @bm1125 Here, the algorithm is considering only the first $i$ functions. And, it finds the maximum value of their sum when the limit is $j$, i.e. $\sum_{t = 1}^{i} x_{t} \leq j$. Maybe you can stare at the solution for some time, and you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using dynamic programming.

For $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$ define $F_i(x)$ as the maximum value $\sum_{j=1}^i f_j(x_j)$ attainable for a suitable choice of $x_1, \dots, x_i$ such that $x_1 + \dots + x_i \le x$.  That is:
$$F_i(x) = \max_{\substack{x_1, \dots, x_i  \in \{0, \dots, m\} \\ x_1 + \dots + x_i \le x}} \sum_{j=1}^i f_j(x_j).
$$

As a special case let $F_0(x) = 0$. You can then write $F_i(x)$, with $i \ge 1$, as follows:
$$
F_i(x) = \max_{y \in \{0, \dots, x\}} \big\{ f_i(y) + F_{i-1}(x-y) \big\}.
$$

Computing all values $F_i(0), \dots, F_i(m)$ in increasing order of $i$ using the above identity immediately yields an algorithm with a running time of $O(m^3)$ to compute the optimal value of $\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(x_i) = F_m(m)$.

Using standard techniques you can then also find an optimal assignment to $x_1, \dots, x_m$.

Comment: A High Five - We posted the same solution at the same time :p